# How to calculate gradually increasing speed when time and distance is known?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I calculate this? How much does the speed need to increase in second in order to reach the destination in 10 seconds? Speed starts at 0.

```
Distance to reach = 1000 meters
Time to reach distance = 10 seconds
Speed increment in second = ?
```

I've been banging my head against the wall for the past few hours, since I just can't figure this out and can't find any help from google... I don't even know if this is a valid question anymore, I am losing hope. I am clearly not that good in math. Sorry if I have the wrong tag on the question, I have no idea what category this question is related to.

Comment: This is a case of constantly accelerated motion. Do you know the equations that describe this kind of motion?

Comment: If you know calculus I can show you from scratch if you'd like

Comment: It appears there are those willing to help. Why not help them? What is your math background? Is this for a course? If not, why has this problem come to your attention?

Comment: @5xum Thanks for responses! Like I said I am not that good in math, so no I don't know any equations for this.

Comment: @JohnDouma My math background is not that great, I went to a vocational school so my basic understanding is really minimal. I need this calculation for my movement system in game development with Unity. I already asked in Unity forums and in stack overflow, but no one was able to help me with this.

Comment: @Crossoni Then... how did you get to this problem? What's the context? Equations describing constantly accelerated motion are usually taught to children aged around 13-15, so unless you are 12, I find it hard to believe you never heard of them...

Comment: @5xum The problem is that I did not pay attention at school when I was 13-15, so everything that was taught during that time went over my head... Same thing in vocational school.

Comment: @Crossoni OK, but you also claim that you "can't find any help from google". But if I type "constantly accelerated motion" into google, I get plenty of useful hits. https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/3-4-motion-with-constant-acceleration and https://www.khanacademy.org/science/high-school-physics/one-dimensional-motion-2/motion-with-constant-acceleration-2/a/1d-kinematics-review-article are the top two hits...

Comment: @5xum Thank you, I will look into that. I was using wrong search words then. I mainly searched for "Accelerate to distance in x seconds" and similar kind of wording, so that got me to physics based calculations and I did not understand a word they said.

Comment: @Crossoni Ah, right, sometimes it pays to know what to google. I suggest you start with the Khan Academy site, it gives you all the equations you will need.

Comment: @Crossoni You can use the formula $x=\frac{1}{2}at^2$. Plug the distance into $x$ and the time into $t$ and solve for $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to calculate acceleration using that formula which Saeed and John Douma posted. I would have never been able to calculate this without help from my relative, since my math understanding is pretty much limited to elementary school math. But here is the whole answer:

$$x = \frac12 a \; t^2$$

$$\frac{x}{\frac12} = at^2$$

$$\frac{\frac{2x}{t^2}}{t^2} = a$$

$$a = \frac{2x}{t^2}$$

$$acceleration = \frac{2\cdot distance}{time^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *speed increment*, which I find a badly worded expression for what is known as *acceleration*.

Acceleration is the rate of change of speed. In your example we are assuming that acceleration is constant, and so speed increases from zero up by a constant amount every second. Note that here we are measuring speed in *meters per second ($\frac ms$)*. So our unit for measuring acceleration is *meters per squared second* ($\frac{m}{s^2}$).

Now, you can solve your problem using mechanics of motion in one dimension. There are a bunch of formulas that describe this kind of motion. We choose the one that works with the data we have. Here we have the distance and time, and we want to find acceleration. Here is the formula:
$$x = \frac12 a \; t^2$$
where $x$ is distance ($m$), $a$ is acceleration ($\frac{m}{s^2}$) and $t$ is time ($s$). You can take it from here, right?